# How to change values of a pandas dataframe column filtered by values of other columns

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, filter

How can I write the below R code in Python?

```
df = data.frame( a=c("apple", "banana", "orange", "apple"),
                 b=c(NA, 3, NA, 5)
                 c=c(2, 1, 0, NA)
                 d=c(1, NA, NA, 3) )

df[ df$a =="apple" & !is.na(df$b), "c"] = df[ df$a =="apple" & !is.na(df$b), "d"]
```

I tried the below and received the TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed error

```
# Python code that receives an error
# df is Pandas DataFrame
df.loc[ (df.a=="apple") & ~df.b.isnull(), 'c'] = df.loc[ (df.a=="apple") & ~df.b.isnull(), 'd']

df['c'] = df.apply( lambda row: row['d'] if row['a']=="apple" & ~np.isnan(row['b']) else row['c'])
```

The expected result is df['c'] will have [2, 1, 0, 3]

Answer (score 1):

In pandas

```
df.loc[ (df.a =="apple") & (df.b.notnull()), "c"]=df.d
```